# The 3D model disappears while zooming

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have several IFC models regularly transformed by model derivative services that disappear completely when viewing and zooming until you get "close enough" to objects that are then shown incomplete.
This behavior is present in all versions of viewer 7.
These models represent large objects (hundreds of meters). Is there a limit to the technology used in Forge?

I can send one of these 3d models for your review.

Thanks for an answer

Gabriele

[image: the whole model]
[image: zooming to an abject partially shown]
[image: zooming]

Comment: Could you share a non-confidential reproducible model demonstrating this issue to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` for our investigations?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occours when the derivative service is called in legacy mode.
Autodesk Support recommends that I use the modern pipeline by calling the transform service with the following parameters:

```
  "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "svf",
         "views": [
           "3d"
         ],
         "advanced": {
            "conversionMethod": "modern"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
```

Thanks Eason